# でさえ and すら in the same sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning, particle-さえ

> 幻想でさえ既知感すら拒絶のはず

さえ and すら in the same sentence? How do I understand this? Like this?

> Even in an illusion even knowledge is supposed to be rejected

Comment: Seems like the whole point of that is to defy understanding. It's a very word salad-y poem http://book.2ch.net/poem/kako/1054/10540/1054046920.html

Answer (score 1):

Based on [the rest of this text](http://book.2ch.net/poem/kako/1054/10540/1054046920.html), it's safe to assume that this is intentionally written to be nonsensical. It is very unlikely that you will see this kind of usage anywhere else.